# submit image with nested form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, nested-forms

Here is my view for post

```
<%= nested_form_for Post.new,url: {action: :create} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title,placeholder: 'Ad title' %>
<%= f.text_area :description, :cols => 80, :rows => 20, :class => 'tinymce' %>
<%= f.fields_for :image, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |uploads| %>
<%= uploads.file_field :upload %>
<button type="submit">Start upload</button>
<% end %>
<input type="submit" />
<% end %>
```

If i click `start upload` it is redirecting to `action: :create`. I need to upload images via ajax. How can i achieve it.

**Edit 1**

I tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function () {
      $('#fileupload').submit(function(){
        alert('test');
      })

  });
</script>
```

But form is directly submitted to `action: :create`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have two separate forms and then use css to display the image in the middle. Otherwise the image will always be submitted with the other form (unless you remove it after the ajax. Try the `remote: true` option for the AJAX upload, however, I'm not sure if it'll work. Uploading with AJAX is quite tricky. I used iframes the last time I had to do it (2 years ago).